# What is sum: $\sum\limits_{m,n\geq1}\frac{1}{(1+mn)^2}$?

Tags: summation, zeta-functions

What is the sum $$\sum\limits_{m,n\geq1}\frac{1}{(1+mn)^2}.$$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$$\begin{eqnarray*} \sum_{m,n\geq 1}\frac{1}{(1+mn)^2} = \sum_{r\geq 1}\frac{d(r)}{(r+1)^2}=\frac{1}{4}+\sum_{r\geq 2}d(r)\left(\frac{1}{r^2}-\frac{2}{r^3}+\frac{3}{r^4}-\ldots\right)\end{eqnarray*}$$
but:
$$ \sum_{r \geq 2}\frac{d(r)}{r^k} = -1+\sum_{r\geq 1}\frac{(1*1)(r)}{r^k} = -1+\zeta(k)^2 $$
so:

> $$\sum_{m,n\geq 1}\frac{1}{(1+mn)^2}=\frac{1}{4}+\sum_{h\geq 2}(h-1)(-1)^h\left(\zeta(h)^2-1\right).$$

Comment: You might be thinking of the pole at $h=1$.  For large $h$, $\zeta(h)-1$ behaves more like $2^{-h}$, so your answer is actually rapidly convergent and quite useful for computation: works out to $1.3902075434437\ldots$, which I'm surprised to see doesn't appear in ISC (assuming I didn't mess up).

Answer (score 3):

I have an idea that might help, but I can't finish:

Note that for each positive integer $k$, the term 
$$\frac1{(1+k)^2}$$
occurs as many times as the number of divisors of $k$, that is
$$\sum_{m,n\ge1}\frac1{(1+mn)^2}=\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{d(k)}{(1+k)^2}$$

where $d(k)$ is the number of divisors of $k$.